# Fetch contract line values based on PO mapped to it using Automation script

Tags: jython, maximo

I have a requirement to fetch CONTRACTLINE details based on the PO to which it has been mapped to it . So I have created an Object launch point on PO which will be triggered during "UPDATE" however the getMbo(0) on CONTRACTLINE is BLANK , I am not sure what is the issue as the count is >0 so ideally it should fetch the values.

```
userInfo=mbo.getUserInfo()
POContractNum = mbo.getString("CONTRACTREFNUM")
POContractRevNum = mbo.getInt("CONTRACTREFREV")
POContractOrgID = mbo.getString("ORGID")
PONum = mbo.getString("PONUM")
ContractSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("CONTRACT",userInfo)
ContractSet.setWhere("CONTRACTNUM = '" + POContractNum + "' and STATUS=  'APPR'  and ORGID = '" + POContractOrgID + "'")
ContractSet.reset()
Contract = ContractSet.getMbo(0)
print 'Contract number', ContractSet.getMbo(0).getString("CONTRACTNUM")
ContractLineSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("CONTRACTLINE",userInfo)
ContractLineSet.setWhere("CONTRACTNUM = '" + POContractNum + "' and  LINESTATUS = 'APPR'  and ORGID = '" + POContractOrgID + "'")
ContractLineSet.reset()
print " Contract Line Where : " + ContractLineSet.getWhere()
print " Contract Lines Selected = " + str(ContractLineSet.count())
print " mbo contract line contract num ",   ContractLineSet.getMbo(0).getString("CONTRACTNUM")
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Contract number PCR1214
Contract Line Where : CONTRACTNUM = 'PCR1214' and LINESTATUS = 'APPR'  and ORGID = 'XXXX'
Contract Lines Selected = 1
mbo contract line contract num
```

Comment: I would call getMbo(0) before calling count()

Comment: I would also use getMboSet() on instances of Mbo, not on instances of MXServer, to avoid the memory leaks present in the code given.

Comment: I tried using getMboSet() with relationship however it didnt work... same blank value . I shall try getMbo(0) before calling count() however I am not sure what different it makes.

Comment: From the Javadocs on MboSet.setWhere, "The Where clause takes effect when the MboSet is reset and a record is fetched." As far as I know, calling count() does not cause a record to be fetched, meaning that calling it after calling setWhere() and reset() will give you meaningless results.

Comment: No it didnt work , below is what I used 
ContractLineSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("CONTRACTLINE",userInfo)
ContractLineSet.setWhere("CONTRACTNUM = '" + POContractNum + "' and LINESTATUS = 'APPR'  and REVSTATUS= 'CHANGED' and ORGID = '" + POContractOrgID + "'")
#ContractLineSet.reset()
print " mbo contract line contract num", ContractLineSet.getMbo(0).getString("CONTRACTNUM")
print " Contract Line Where : " + ContractLineSet.getWhere()
print " Contract Lines Selected = " + str(ContractLineSet.count())

Comment: Can you confirm the queries being executed against the database? Set the Log Level to INFO for the sql / CONTRACTLINE logger. Once you get the query out of the logs, run it for yourself and see what comes back.

Comment: Also, you could show yourself whether ContractLineSet.getMbo(0).toBeAdded() returns true or false. I don't know why it would be true, but something isn't right and this is something we can check.

Comment: Yes the query is correct , select * from contractline where contractnum='XXX' and linestatus='APPR' and REVSTATUS='CHANGED' and orgid='YYY' . Additionally when I tried to print ContractLineSet.getMbo(0).toBeAdded() returns BLANK ( neither TRUE or FALSE).

Comment: you're sure there are no additional errors in the systemout.log or systemerr.log?

Comment: any luck with the logfiles?

Comment: The link that you had shared worked .. it was some other script on CONTRACTLINE  object which was causing the problem and when I deactivated that it did worked. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I ran into a very similar problem earlier. Please review the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27423780/1341373

Comment: I remember seeing this before posting this question however it didn't work. I have added the code again and let me know if I have made any mistake .

Comment: `setWhere = "CONTRACTNUM = '" + POContractNum + "' and LINESTATUS = 'APPR'  and REVSTATUS= 'CHANGED' and ORGID = '" + POContractOrgID + "'"
 print 'setwhere' , setWhere 
 ilSet = mbo.getMboSet("$ContractLineRelationship",  "CONTRACTLINE", setWhere)
 print 'set', ilSet
 print 'first mbo value', ilSet.getMbo(0)
 ilMbo = ilSet.moveFirst()
 print ' first value', ilMbo 
 print 'contractnum', ilSet.moveFirst().getString("CONTRACTNUM")`

Comment: `+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  setwhere CONTRACTNUM = 'C1234' and LINESTATUS = 'APPR'  and   REVSTATUS= 'CHANGED' and ORGID = 'XXXXX'
  set psdi.app.contract.ContractLineSet@4a944a94
first mbo value                                                                                          `

Comment: so it does return an object... did it print the contractnum as well? Please note that ilSet.getMbo(0) does not return a value, but an object. This will only work of the ilSet is not empty.

Comment: `print 'first mbo value' , ilSet.getMbo(0)` is BLANK which i don't think is correct. it should have printed the value of the object . Also if you look at my second comment then nothing has got printed after " first mbo value" . So contractnum is BLANK